# python command line encode error

Tags: python, unicode, runtime-error

In python command line I wrote this command.

```
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

for item in g_data:
    print(item.contents[0].text)
```

However it did not work.

> Program said "UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character
>   '\u20a9' in position 90: illegal multibyte sequence".

What should I do?
Give me some advice.

Comment: See http://bit.ly/unipain

Comment: `\u20a9` is ₩ and your terminal can't display that char using the cp949 code page. Can you set the terminal's encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: I don't know exactly how to set terminal's encoding to UTF-8. Please let me know it.

Comment: I assume you're using some version of Windows. The easiest way to temporarily change the code page in the CMD prompt window to UTF-8 is with the `CHCP 65001` command. [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/927575) shows various ways to make UTF-8 the default so you don't need to manually set it every time you open a command prompt window.